# Select date range in one calendar

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I really like plugin daterangepicker, but it uses 2 calendars for selecting a date range.[image]

Is it possible to select a date range with only 1 calendar? do you know other plugins?

I want to make something like that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can refer the below link. It might help you.

http://www.daterangepicker.com/

```
 <input type="text" name="daterange" value="01/01/2015 - 01/31/2015" />

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $('input[name="daterange"]').daterangepicker();
});
</script>
```

Comment: but it has 2 calendars... not one

Comment: well, i can hide the other one :-) display: none

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `singleDatePicker` on the calendar configuration, and set it true.

```
singleDatePicker: true,
```

http://www.daterangepicker.com/#example3

[image]